# Blowfish crypt returns 0* few times

Tags: php, mysql, blowfish

I'm new in this world. I'm studying at the school and I am doing a shopping web site.

I have a function who crypt the password that I send to my database in blowfish:

```
private function encriptarPassword($clave){
    echo $this->passwordRegistro;
    /*salt declaration*/
    $salt="";
    for ($x=0; $x<22; $x++){
        $salt.=substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz0123456789", mt_rand(0, 63), 1);
    }
    return crypt($clave,"$2y$08$".$salt);
}
```

Once I come to create the user in my BBDD (using insert query), sometimes shows me 0* (in phpMyAdmin) error and other times the password is correct.

As you can see, this is an example on my DDBB:

[DDBB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Q4Q.png)

I don't know what happens. I tried to change the password file in my DDBB from varchar(70) to varchar(255) but the problem persists.

My PHP version is 7.0.5.

Would you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in [password API](http://php.net/password)?

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer. I am not using the password API because I need to follow my project's requeriments.

Comment: The `$clave` variable must not be too long with blowfish and, if it is a binary string, it must not contain the 'null byte' (0x00) as that will mark the end of the string.

Comment: Hi Ryan. So, i can't place a long password with blowfish. This could be a reason... but sometimes I try to create a test user and I type a test password like "test" "123456" and don't work. I am going to check it. Big thanks.

Comment: you are aware that your salt string characters is 62 character long not 64? (2 + 26 + 26 + 10)?  You missed the letter **'V'**? This is resulting on a `null` character which confuses the routine so it returns zero.

Comment: Here is the reason. Big thanks Ryan.